# Why the form submission is possible even after form fields are empty?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**Here is the HTML**

```
<form  action="../phpFiles/reportCalorie.php" method="post"  
 onsubmit="return calculateCalorie()" name="bmiform">
                    <select name="activity" >
                        <option value="">Select any activity</option>
                        <option value="1">baseball</option>
                        <option value="2">basketball</option>
                        <option value="3">jogging</option>
                        <option value="4">walking</option>
                        <option value="5">Cycling</option>
                        <option value="6">Running</option>
                        <option value="7">Swimming</option>
                        <option value="8">Handball</option>
                        <option value="9">Cricket</option>
                        <option value="10">Football</option>
                    </select>       

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><h4>How many minutes?</h4></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="minutes" size="5px"/>
                     minutes
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h4>Enter your weight</h4></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="weight" size="5px"/>
                     KG

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h4>Enter your Age</h4></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="age" size="5px"/>
                     Years

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h4>Enter your height</h4></td>
                <td>

                    <input type="text" name="feet" size="5px"/>
                    FEET
                    <input type="text" name="inches" size="5px"/>
                    inches

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <input class="button1" type="submit" name="calculate" 
      value="Calculate" title="calculate" onclick="calculateCalorie()"/>
                <br/><br/>
                </form>
```

**Here is the Javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateCalorie()
    {
      if(validate())
      {           
            var minutes=+document.bmiform.minutes.value;
            var weight=+document.bmiform.weight.value;

            return true 
      }
      else
      {
            return false;
      }
    }

    function validate()
    {
        var age    = document.bmiform.age.value;
        var feet   = document.bmiform.feet.value;
        var inches = document.bmiform.inches.value;
        var weight = document.bmiform.weight.value;
        var minutes= document.bmiform.minutes.value;

        if(age =="" || feet=="" || inches=="" || weight=="" || minutes=="")
        {
            alert("Your fields are empty");
            return false
        }

        else if(isNaN(age) || isNaN(feet) || isNaN(inches) || 
        isNaN(weight) isNaN(minutes) )
        {
            alert("Please enter valid input")
            return false;

        }
        else{
            return true;
        }

    }
    </script>
```

I do not understand that even i left the field empty why it accepting the form and direct me to other page. please if anything is wrong just let me know? I would greatly appreciated any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(isNaN(age) || isNaN(feet) || isNaN(inches) || 
        isNaN(weight) isNaN(minutes) )
```

You`ve missed "||" operator here. It triggers a syntax error, which fails further javascript execution.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code your missing an || operator

```js
        else if(isNaN(age) || isNaN(feet) || isNaN(inches) || 
        isNaN(weight) || isNaN(minutes) )
        {
            alert("Please enter valid input")
            return false;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 minor issues with the code, one being the cause of the error. The first is that there's a syntax error in the `isNaN` check which should be changed to `isNaN(weight) || isNaN(minutes)`.

Second, the `<input ...` has an `onclick` listener in addition to your form's `onsubmit` listener, which runs the validation twice and could cause problems later on.

(Note that I changed the alert into console.log, so the snippet would work)

```js
    function calculateCalorie()
    {
      if(validate())
      {           
            var minutes=+document.bmiform.minutes.value;
            var weight=+document.bmiform.weight.value;

            console.log('submitting');
            return true 
      }
      else
      {
            return false;
      }
    }

    function validate()
    {
        var age    = document.bmiform.age.value;
        var feet   = document.bmiform.feet.value;
        var inches = document.bmiform.inches.value;
        var weight = document.bmiform.weight.value;
        var minutes= document.bmiform.minutes.value;

        if(age =="" || feet=="" || inches=="" || weight=="" || minutes=="")
        {
            console.log("Your fields are empty");
            return false;
        }

        else if(isNaN(age) || isNaN(feet) || isNaN(inches) || 
        isNaN(weight) || isNaN(minutes) )
        {
            console.log("Please enter valid input")
            return false;

        }
        else{
            return true;
        }

    }
```

```html
<form  action="../phpFiles/reportCalorie.php" method="post"  
 onsubmit="return calculateCalorie()" name="bmiform">
                    <select name="activity" >
                        <option value="">Select any activity</option>
                        <option value="1">baseball</option>
                        <option value="2">basketball</option>
                        <option value="3">jogging</option>
                        <option value="4">walking</option>
                        <option value="5">Cycling</option>
                        <option value="6">Running</option>
                        <option value="7">Swimming</option>
                        <option value="8">Handball</option>
                        <option value="9">Cricket</option>
                        <option value="10">Football</option>
                    </select>       

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><h4>How many minutes?</h4></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="minutes" size="5px"/>
                     minutes
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h4>Enter your weight</h4></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="weight" size="5px"/>
                     KG

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h4>Enter your Age</h4></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="age" size="5px"/>
                     Years

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h4>Enter your height</h4></td>
                <td>

                    <input type="text" name="feet" size="5px"/>
                    FEET
                    <input type="text" name="inches" size="5px"/>
                    inches

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <input class="button1" type="submit" name="calculate" 
      value="Calculate" title="calculate" />
                <br/><br/>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also call preventDefault to prevent the default form.

```
function customSubmitFunction(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  someBug();
  return false;
}
```

In this case, even with the bug the form won't submit!

Comment: like what kind of bug?

Comment: bug here refers to anything that causes an error and breaks javascript execution.